# Using a computer display as an eXtreme feedback device

Tags: continuous-integration, extreme-feedback-devices

I have a test server that sits in the corner of our office.  I would like a extreme feedback device, which I like to call a 'screen', to show me the status of the build.  Yes, it's boring compared to lava lamps and rabbits, but it's readily available and takes less faff to set up.

The machine is running Linux.  Does anyone have any suggestions for software good at displaying nice big blocks of colour and text, easily visible across a room, in response to external events?  My last resort is to write a bit of wxPerl, but I thought I would check to see what other people have done first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla use a web site to present build status - [is the tree green](http://isthetreegreen.com/); details [here](http://blog.mozilla.com/dolske/2009/01/25/is-the-tree-green/).

Comment: Websites respond to the event 'someone is looking at me'.  A screen really needs to respond to the event 'the situation has changed'.  META REFRESH would do at a push, but I was hoping for something a bit more exciting to look at...

Comment: HTML is quite enough for "big blocks of colour and text". Use Javascript timer for a smoother update, polling whatever data as often as you like.